# MENU: hover not working after I do click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I know there's a lot of post asking the same question, but since is too complicated for me understand, coz Im newb in css, js, and html.

So when my page load. hover works perfectly, then when I click an option... (do some js code) then hover doesn't work. Im trying to figure out why this is happening. But I have not idea.

This is a simple code (Please try to not use another language than css3, html5 and javascript)...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
 body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: gray;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
 }
  a:hover {
   color: white ;
   background: black ;
  }
 ul {
  list-style: none;
 }
 #parrafo {
  border: 1px dashed white;
  height: 1.2em;
 }

</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->
<body>
 <br/>
 <div id="d1">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="op1" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <p id="parrafo"></p>
 </div>
</body>

<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>

 
 
 function clearOP(par) {
  var i, n;
  
  n = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
  
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   document.getElementById('op'+i).style.color = 'black';
   document.getElementById('op'+i).style.background = 'white';
  }
 }
 
 function SelectOp(param) {
  var i, x;
  
  i=1;
  while (param != 'op'+i) {
   i++;
  }
  
  clearOP(param);
  document.getElementById('op'+i).style.color = 'white';
  document.getElementById('op'+i).style.background = 'black';
  
 }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the style using script it override your CSS hover rule.

Toggle a class instead.

I also optimized your script a little, no need to use all that code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  a.selected {                     /* added this class */
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  #parrafo {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    height: 1.2em;
  }
</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->

<body>
  <br/>
  <div id="d1" value="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="op1" class="selected" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
  </div>
</body>

<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>

  function SelectOp(param) {
    document.querySelector('.selected').className = '';
    document.getElementById(param).className = 'selected';
  }
  
</script>

</html>
```

---

I also want to recommend to not use inline scripting, use event listeners, like in this sample

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#d1 a');   /*  find all anchor inside #d1         */

elems[0].className = 'selected';                  /*  set first as selected              */

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {          /*  iterate all and add click handler  */
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('.selected').className = '';
    e.target.className = 'selected';
  })
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #333;
  }
  a.selected {                     /* added this class */
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  #parrafo {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    height: 1.2em;
  }
```

```html
<br/>
  <div id="d1" value="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="op1">OP1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op2">OP2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op3">OP3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op4">OP4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op5">OP5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: This appears to be a proficient solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @vincentthorpe Thank you, the 2:nd sample I recommend you start use, it will save you a lot work in the future

Answer (score 1):

## Use CSS Classes - [Online Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LzjkY8WIv8IF2P3YEGMk?p=preview)

Instead of directly setting the color, you can toggle a css class.

add `a.selected` next to `a:hover` in css

```
a.selected,
a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

Simplify your code to be class dependent

```
<script>
    SelectOp('op1');


    function clearOP() {
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].className = '';
      };
    }

    function SelectOp(id) {
      clearOP();
      document.getElementById(id).className = 'selected';
    }
</script>
```

#### https://plnkr.co/edit/LzjkY8WIv8IF2P3YEGMk?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  #parrafo {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    height: 1.2em;
  }
  .op_active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->

<body onload="berep()">
  <br/>
  <div id="d1" value="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="op1" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
  </div>
</body>

<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>
  function berep() {
    document.getElementById('op1').classList.add("op_active");
  }

  function clearOP(par) {
    var i, n;

    n = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      var el = document.getElementById('op' + i);
      el.classList.remove("op_active");
    }
  }

  function SelectOp(param) {
    var i, x;

    i = 1;
    while (param != 'op' + i) {
      i++;
    }

    clearOP(param);
    var el = document.getElementById('op' + i);
    el.classList.add("op_active");
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are changing the elements style attribute directly in DOM instead you should use the classes. Check the below updated snippet , hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  .white-black{
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }

  .black-white{
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  #parrafo {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    height: 1.2em;
  }
</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->

<body onload="berep()">
  <br/>
  <div id="d1" value="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="op1" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
  </div>
</body>

<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>
  function berep() {
    document.getElementById('op1').className = "white-black"
  }

  function clearOP(par) {
    var i, n;

    n = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     document.getElementById('op' + i).className = "black-white"
    }
  }

  function SelectOp(param) {
    var i, x;

    i = 1;
    while (param != 'op' + i) {
      i++;
    }

    clearOP(param);
  document.getElementById('op' + i).className = "white-black";
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Other option will be to use `!important` in your hover selector.

Comment: Something like `color: white !important;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the color and background for the element you select, I just made the modification.

```
if(par==i){
        i++;
        continue;
      }
```

Just add the above if statement in your clearOP function's for loop

```
<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>
  function berep() {
    document.getElementById('op1').style.color = 'white';
    document.getElementById('op1').style.background = 'black';
  }

  function clearOP(par) {
    var i, n;

    n = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      console.log("Clear OP"+  i);
      if(par==i){
        i++;
        continue;
      }
      document.getElementById('op' + i).style.color = 'black';
      document.getElementById('op' + i).style.background = 'white';
    }
  }

  function SelectOp(param) {
    var i, x;

    i = 1;
    while (param != 'op' + i) {
      i++;
      console.log(i);
    }

    clearOP(param);
    document.getElementById('op' + i).style.color = 'white';
    document.getElementById('op' + i).style.background = 'black';
  }
</script>
```

```js
  function berep() {
    document.getElementById('op1').style.color = 'white';
    document.getElementById('op1').style.background = 'black';
  }

  function clearOP(par) {
    var i, n;

    n = document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      //console.log("Clear OP"+  i);
      if(par==i){
        i++;
        continue;
      }
      document.getElementById('op' + i).style.color = 'black';
      document.getElementById('op' + i).style.background = 'white';
    }
  }

  function SelectOp(param) {
    var i, x;

    i = 1;
    while (param != 'op' + i) {
      i++;
      //console.log(i);
    }

    clearOP(param);
    document.getElementById('op' + i).style.color = 'white';
    document.getElementById('op' + i).style.background = 'black';
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: gray;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  #parrafo {
    border: 1px dashed white;
    height: 1.2em;
  }
</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->

<body onload="berep()">
  <br/>
  <div id="d1" value="0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="op1" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <p id="parrafo"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click an element, you set **inline** styles (for the clicked you set black background, and for the others white background).

After the click, all the elements have inline styles.

**Inline styles have higher priority than styles that applied by selectors** (a or a:hover).

Thats why you don't see hover styles after click, because you alredy have inline styles.

Insted of giving styles to all elements on click try the following approach:

Create a class called "selected":

```
selected {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
```

on click remove this class from all elements, then set the class for the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

First Thanks all for helping me with my basic menu. I just found the solution reading your answers, it was very helpful. Now I have a clearly nearest idea how css3, html5 and Js work. So I found a good solution via @Jossef Harush and I just wanted to share my code with you. I also optimized a little bit my code. Again thanks!.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<!--___________________STYLES-->
<style>
 body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: gray;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
 }
  .selected,
  a:hover {
   color: white;
   background: black;
  }
 ul {
  list-style: none;
 }
 #parrafo {
  border: 1px dashed white;
  height: 1.2em;
 }
</style>

<!--___________________BODY-->
<body>
 <br/>
 <div id="d1">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="op1" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op2" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op3" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op4" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="op5" onClick="SelectOp(this.id)">OP5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <p id="parrafo"></p>
 </div>
</body>

<!--___________________JAVSCRIPT-->
<script>
 var sel = '1';
 SelectOp('op1');
 
 function SelectOp(param) {
  document.getElementById('op'+sel).className = '';
  sel = param.charAt(2);
  document.getElementById(param).className = 'selected';
 }
</script>
</html>
```